# Sqlalchemy Fuzzystrmatch with Postgres extension

Tags: python, sql, regex, python-3.x, postgresql

I am using the Postgres extension `fuzzystrmatch`.
I want to replicate this (query) to the sqlalchemy ORM.

Example

```sql
SELECT * FROM mymodel WHERE soundex(denomination, 'PHONE') > 0.4;
```

That the match limit can be changed.

In sqlalchemy I am doing like this, but it does not work:

```
MyModel.query.filter(func.soundex(MyModel.denomination) == func.soundex('PHONE') > 0.4).all()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute it as a raw sql:

```
with engine.connect() as con:
    rs = con.execute("""SELECT * FROM mymodel WHERE SIMILARITY(denomination, 'PHONE') > 0.4""")
```